# Create a new column in a dataframe using a function

Tags: function, dataframe

So I think I am having a simple problem.

I have a dataframe (my_data), that looks like this

```
Treatment Amount Duration
a        5         3000
b        8         2000
c        6         1000
d        2         5000
```

Now I want to create a new dataframe (my_data_1) which adds a new column based on a simple function `Duration/Amount`.

`My_data_1` should look like this:

```
Treatment Amount Duration  Mean duration
    a        5         3000     600
    b        8         2000     250
    c        6         1000     167
    d        2         5000    2500
```

I tried to write a function and implement it into my dataframe

```
mean_duration <- function(md){my_data$Duration / my_data$Amount}

my_data_1$md <- with(my_data, ave(Duration, Amount, FUN = mean_duration))
```

Where did I go wrong?